# Axios fetch requests not working on cPanel hosted React + Node.js web app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, axios, hosting, cpanel

I have a React + Express app that is fetching the data normally when on localhost.
On public domain, React app loads, but it throws this error on my fetch requests "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Also I don't know if this is relevant, but the screen is blank when no port number or port number 443 in Axios request URL is put, but when I put 80 or 8080, the site loads.

My backend and frontend are on the same URL, that could also be the problem, even though I have seen that it is possible to have both on the same URL.

Please help because I'm not sure if I have messed up somewhere in my code, or in cPanel setup of the Node.js app.

I tried testing through Postman, and it returns me the HTML of my React application instead of the data from my database.

I have also tried downgrading Node.js version in the application setup and it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are two issues.

1. Your API tests should return the data, not a webpage. Check the configuration to ensure traffic to domain.com/your-api-name is actually routed to the port with nodejs running.
2. The Connection refused error could be a CORS issue. Try adding the following code to your index.js file, above app.use().

   const cors = require("cors");
   app.use(cors());

then, inside an app.use() method, include the following:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const allowedOrigins = [
    
    "http://your-domain-name.com",
  ];
  const origin = req.headers.origin;

  allowedOrigins.includes(origin) &&
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);

  // Request methods you wish to allow
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");

  // Request headers you wish to allow
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "content-type");

  // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
  // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

  // Pass to next layer of middleware
  next();
});
```

This allows requests to be made from your api, from your domain name.

Comment: By checking the configuration do you mean in cPanel? And if so, how would I do that?

Comment: You'll have to look into port forwarding with cpanel. I'm from a Nginx background so can't help you with specifics with this in cpanel, but the same principle will apply. You need to tell your firewall to send domain.com/api requests to your node.js app's port. Hope this helps!

Comment: Agreed on p.1, but on p.2 - CORS issues lead to other types of errors. Also, the backend seems to be on the same subdomain. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED means "no network connection" e.g. due to firewall or just wrong host/port.

Answer (score 0):

If on 443 it does not work it means you have not setup ssl certificate for your domain

Comment: In SSL/TLS Status it says that i have a SSL certificate for my domain.